# Sine Tone that is constantly changing based on time related variables

Tags: python, variables, audio, time, live

```
    #Sine wave calculations by vegaseat.
#The program will take in the current time that the computer has, and turn that into a
#tone that is unique to that moment in time.  It then makes an accompaning graph to
#view for easier comparison of the sound and an interesting view of the sound heard.

from Tkinter import *
from struct import pack
from math import sin, pi
import math
import time
import os


def wave():
    #time based variables
    t = time.strftime("%S", time.localtime())
    ti = time.strftime("%M", time.localtime())
    tis = float(t)
    tis = tis / 100
    tim = float(ti)
    tim = tim / 100


    root = Tk()
    root.title("The moment")

    #variables for canvas
    width = 800
    height = 600
    center = height//2
    x_increment = 2
    # width stretch
    x_factor1 = tis
    x_factor2 = tim
    # height stretch
    y_amplitude = 50

    #new canvas
    c = Canvas(width=width, height=height, bg="black")
    c.pack()

    str1 = "sin(x)=white"
    c.create_text(10, 20, anchor=SW, text=str1)

    center_line = c.create_line(0, center, width, center, fill="red")

    # create the coordinate list for the sin() curve, have to be integers
    xy1 = []
    xy2 = []
    for x in range(400):
        # x coordinates
        xy1.append(x * x_increment)
        xy2.append(x * x_increment)
        # y coordinates
        xy1.append(int(math.sin(x * x_factor1) * y_amplitude) + center)
        xy2.append(int(math.sin(x * x_factor2) * y_amplitude) + center)

    #create the lines
    sinS_line = c.create_line(xy1, fill="white")
    sinM_line = c.create_line(xy2, fill="yellow")

    root.mainloop()

def au_file(name, freq, freq1, dur, vol):
    fout = open(name, "wb")
    # header needs size, encoding=2, sampling_rate=8000, channel=1
    fout.write(".snd" + pack(">5L", 24, 8*dur, 2, 8000, 1))
    factor = 2 * pi * freq/8000
    factor1 = 2 * pi * freq1/8000
    # write data
    for seg in range(8 * dur):
        # sine wave calculations
        sin_seg = sin(seg * factor) + sin(seg * factor1)
        fout.write(pack("b", vol * 64 * sin_seg))
    fout.close()
#time based variables
t = time.strftime("%S", time.localtime())
ti = time.strftime("%M", time.localtime())
tis = float(t)
tis = tis * 100
tim = float(ti)
tim = tim * 100
os.startfile("timeSound.au")

#running it using main.
def main():
    au_file(name="timeSound.au", freq=tim, freq1=tis, dur=1000, vol=1.0)
    wave()

main()
```

This is my program that takes the minutes and takes and has them effect a sine wave tone for a tone based on the time (kind of).  It creates the sound file and then plays it.  What I want is a live streaming sine wave that is effected by the time down to milliseconds for a constant fluctuating tone.  Is that possible? If so, what can I use to have the sound play live and how can I have the variables be connected to the time and be live themselves?

Comment: Do you have a function describing what you would like the frequency to be at a given time?

Comment: I just want the frequency to be changing by the computers clock values as boolean variables.  So the frequency is 'def au_file(name, freq, freq1, dur, vol):
    fout = open(name, "wb")
    # header needs size, encoding=2, sampling_rate=8000, channel=1
    fout.write(".snd" + pack(">5L", 24, 8*dur, 2, 8000, 1))
    factor = 2 * pi * freq/8000
    factor1 = 2 * pi * freq1/8000
    # write data
    for seg in range(8 * dur):
        # sine wave calculations
        sin_seg = sin(seg * factor) + sin(seg * factor1)
        fout.write(pack("b", vol * 64 * sin_seg))
    fout.close()'

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach you can take for a continuous varying frequency:

```
def gen_scale(samples_per_wave, samples_per_change):
    pi2 = 2 * math.pi
    rad = 0
    while (samples_per_wave > 1):
        for i in range(0, samples_per_change):
            yield math.sin(rad)
            rad = rad + pi2 / samples_per_wave
            if (rad > pi2):
                rad = rad - pi2
        samples_per_wave = samples_per_wave - 1
```

`samples_per_wave` is basically the inverse of the `Hz` measurement (this sound will increase in frequency). `samples_per_change` is how many samples the generator produces before incrementally adjusting the frequency.

Comment: this will create a tone with varying frequency over time, correct? My goal is to have python generate a tone that is a live stream with its frequency being effected by variables based upon the computer's clock.  Also I believe that I will need another library that can generate and play a tone rather than rely on the user's defaulted program.  Any suggestions on a library that can generate and play a tone that also meets the requirements of the original question.

Comment: @Weeds: This can easily be adapted in the manner you desire. radian measure is advanced by `pi2 / samples_per_wave`. This parameter does not have be produced in a continuously varying loop. It can be provided from the outside and frobbed up and down at well.